# How to set python library constant in Spark/databricks cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I have a python databricks notebook doing batch inference with fastai v2 via a pandas UDF. This throws `PIL.Image.DecompressionBombError` on some large images.

Setting

```
Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None
```

sets it only on the driver. How does one set it globally across the cluster to avoid `PIL.Image.DecompressionBombError` on the workers?

Comment: set it inside the UDF itself?

Comment: Thx. I tried this, but it still throws the error.